# Exact sequences and (semi) direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

Let $0 \longrightarrow H \longrightarrow G  \longrightarrow K \longrightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence. My question is quite general: how can one recover $G$ knowing $H$ and $K$?

1. Naive question: is $G$ isomorphic to $ H \times K$? Clearly not, take any non trivial semidirect product.
2. Is $G$ isomorphic to a semidirect product between $H$ and $K$? It seems very unlikely since in that case $K$ would have to lift to a subgroup of $G$, but I can't think of a counterexample.
3. Under this last assumption (that $K$ lifts to a subgroup of $H$ on which the restriction of the last arrow induces an isomorphism), is $G$ isomorphic to a semidirect product between $H$ and $K$?
4. More generally, are there classification of short exact sequences under nontrivial assumptions?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Point 4 in full generality is the [extension problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Extension_problem), which is a seriously difficult one.

For point $2$, take $G$ to be the cyclic group of order $4$, and $H$ its subgroup of order $2$.

For point 3, yes. (Of course you mean *$K$ lifts to a subgroup of $G$*.)

An important special case of point 4 is the [Schur–Zassenhaus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-Zassenhaus_theorem), for the case when $H$ and $K$ have coprime orders.

Comment: Thanks. A hint for point 3. ?

Comment: @SelimGhazouani Call $\varphi$ the morphism $G \to K$. You are assuming that there is a morphism $\psi : K \to G$ such that $\varphi \circ \psi$ is the identity on $K$. Show that $\psi(K)$ is a complement for $H$ in $G$, that is $G = H \psi(K)$ and $H \cap \psi(K) = \{1\}$.